# Finding out installed packages in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been at it for some time and tried everything.

I need to find out whether the package **GraphFrames** is included in the spark installation at my office cluster. I am using **Spark version 1.5.0**.

Is there a way to list all the installed packages in Spark?

Comment: import the package and see if a test job succeeds or fails? Look for the relevant .jar file?

Answer (score -1):

include the package anyway to be sure eg via spak submit:
  $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6